# Angular EXCEPTION: No provider for Http

Tags: angular

I am getting the `EXCEPTION: No provider for Http!` in my Angular app. What am I doing wrong?

```
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'


@Component({
    selector: 'greetings-ac-app2',
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: 'app/greetings-ac2.html',
    directives: [NgFor, NgModel, NgIf, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: []
})
export class GreetingsAcApp2 {
    private str:any;

    constructor(http: Http) {

        this.str = {str:'test'};

        http.post('http://localhost:18937/account/registeruiduser/',
            JSON.stringify(this.str),
            {
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                })
            });
```

Comment: You are missing `HTTP_PROVIDERS`.

Comment: import/export... please, anybody, what syntax is this?

Comment: It is Typescript Syntax

Comment: import/export - it's JavaScript syntax (ES6)

Comment: yes there is missing `HTTP_PROVIDER` as already answer. but if you further want more info about `HTTP` you can take a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758630/5043867

Comment: It'd be nice if one of the answers actually explained **why** we need to import `HttpModule`, and what it does.

Answer (score 528, accepted):

Import the HttpModule

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
    providers: [],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export default class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Ideally, you split up this code in two separate files.
For further information read:

- https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html
- https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Comment: In current Angular2 beta the file is called `app.ts`.

Comment: In angular-cli generated projects, the file is called `main.ts`.

Comment: what if I don't have a NgModule? I'm developing an angular2 module and it does not have a NgModule but for tests I need Http provider

Comment: @Webruster I just checked. It should still work. Can you give me the exact error code?

Comment: @PhilipMiglinci  ...thanks for the valuable answer .. adding some points for the seekers that the file would be **app.module.ts** in angular 2.0 for explanation this is the core file for the project to include the modules which will use further inherited classes.

Comment: Don't forget to also add it to imports (under @NgModule) as shown in the answer, otherwise it doesn't work (for me).

Answer (score 57):

**>= Angular 4.3**

for the introduced `HttpClientModule`

```ts
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, // if used
    HttpClientModule,
    JsonpModule // if used
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Angular2 >= RC.5**

Import `HttpModule` to the module where you use it (here for example the `AppModule`:

```ts
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, // if used
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule // if used
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Importing the `HttpModule` is quite similar to adding `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in previous version.

Answer (score 9):

Since **rc.5** you have to do something like

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule],
    providers: [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ],  
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export default class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 9):

With the Sept 14, 2016 Angular 2.0.0 release, you are using still using HttpModule. Your main `app.module.ts` would look something like this:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
   declarations: [ AppComponent ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpModule,
      // ...more modules...
   ],
   providers: [
      // ...providers...
   ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in your `app.ts` you can bootstrap as such:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/main/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 9):

Add HttpModule to imports array in **app.module.ts** file before you use it.

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CarsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
 HttpModule  
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 6):

because it was only in the comment section I repeat the answer from Eric:

I had to include `HTTP_PROVIDERS`

Comment: ... Plus, HTTP_PROVIDERS has been depreciated.  It's now called *HttpModule*..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903607/ng2-rc5-http-providers-is-deprecated

Answer (score 5):

Import `HttpModule` in your app.module.ts file.

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { YourHttpTestService } from '../services/httpTestService';
```

Also remember to declare HttpModule under imports like below:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to change your component's decorator by adding Http in providers array as below.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'greetings-ac-app2',
    providers: [Http],
    templateUrl: 'app/greetings-ac2.html',
    directives: [NgFor, NgModel, NgIf, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: []
})
```

Comment: Who soever has marked it wrong, May i know what is the reason?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the reason is probably that you don't want a new `Http` object for each component. Better to have a single one for the app, which is accomplished by importing it at the `NgModule` level.

Answer (score 3):

as of RC5 you need to import the HttpModule like so :

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

then include the HttpModule in the imports array as mentioned above by Günter.

Answer (score 3):

Just include the following libraries:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { YourHttpTestService } from '../services/httpTestService';
```

and include the http class in `providers` section, as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: './test.html',
  providers: [YourHttpTestService]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have this error in your tests, you should create Fake Service for all services:

For example:

```
import { YourService1 } from '@services/your1.service';
import { YourService2 } from '@services/your2.service';

class FakeYour1Service {
 public getSomeData():any { return null; }
}

class FakeYour2Service {
  public getSomeData():any { return null; }
}
```

And in beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      Your1Service,
      Your2Service,
      { provide: Your1Service, useClass: FakeYour1Service },
      { provide: Your2Service, useClass: FakeYour2Service }
    ]
  }).compileComponents();  // compile template and css
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
**
```

> Simple soultion : Import the HttpModule and HttpClientModule on your **app.module.ts**

**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';



@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent, videoComponent, tagDirective, 
 ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule, routing, HttpClientModule, HttpModule

],
providers: [ApiServices],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This solution works, but HttpModule is marked as deprecated in Angular 5.2. I think some component is not upgraded, and still uses the old Http implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in my code. I only put this code in my app.module.ts.

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please don't repeat existing answers. Doing so doesn't add value to the community.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to include the following libraries in tour **app.module.ts** and also include it in your imports:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports:    [ HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

`import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';` package in your module.ts file and add it in your imports.

Answer (score 1):

I just add both these in my app.module.ts:

```
"import { HttpClientModule }    from '@angular/common/http';
```

&

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';"
```

Now its works fine....
And dont forget to add in the

`@NgModule => Imports:[] array`