# Angular2 RC6 HttpModule manual injection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular2-injection

I'm migrating a project from angular2 RC4 to RC6 and I have a custom Form Validator which needs `Http`.
Before the migration I used the `ReflectiveInjector` with the `HTTP_PROVIDERS`, but with RC6 this is not possible anymore as `HTTP_PROVIDERS` is deprecated, respectively not present anymore.
This is the static method in the Validator:

```
    static checkVat(control: FormControl) {
    let checkVatUrl = "http://localhost:8080/checkvat";


    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
    let http = injector.get(Http);
    let authHttp = new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http);

    if (control.value === "") {
        return new Observable((obs: any) => {
            obs.next(null);
            obs.complete();
        });
    } else {
        return authHttp.get(checkVatUrl + "/" + control.value)
            .map((data: Response) => {
                if (data.json().valid) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    let reason = "isNotValidVat";
                    return {[reason]: true};
                }
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                return new Observable((obs: any) => {
                    obs.complete();
                });
            });
    }
}
```

Just replacing `HTTP_PROVIDERS` with `HttpModule` didn't work, I found a similar problem here on stackoverflow ([NG2 RC5: HTTP_PROVIDERS is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903607/ng2-rc5-http-providers-is-deprecated)) regarding testing, but the only answer is specific for testing.

How do I manually "inject" `Http` or `HttpModule` with RC6, if there is another or better solution for this custom Validator I'm open to that too.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
The `checkVat` method is static, that is why I had to use the ReflectiveInjector and not just inject it via the constructor, like everywhere else.
The custom Validator gets used like this:

```
this.vatCtrl = new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.pattern(this.vatService.vatPattern)]),VatValidator.checkVat);
```

UPDATE2:
With the help of Günther Zöchbauer's answer I changed the Code as follows to get it working without a static function and no need for manual injection:

The Validator:

```
@Injectable()
```

export class VatValidator {

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
}

checkVat(control: FormControl) {

    let checkVatUrl = "http://localhost:8080/checkvat";

    let authHttp = new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), this.http);

    if (control.value === "") {
        return new Observable((obs: any) => {
            obs.next(null);
            obs.complete();
        });
    } else {
        return authHttp.get(checkVatUrl + "/" + control.value)
            .map((data: Response) => {
                if (data.json().valid) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    let reason = "isNotValidVat";
                    return {[reason]: true};
                }
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                return new Observable((obs: any) => {
                    obs.complete();
                });
            });
    }

}
```

}

In the component which has the FormControl:

```
    constructor(private vatValidator: VatValidator) {

    this.vatCtrl = new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.pattern(vatPattern)]), this.vatValidator.checkVat.bind(this.vatValidator));

}
```

Comment: Why do you need `let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);` instead of just `constructor(private http:Http){}`?

Comment: Because `checkVat` is static. I will add the use of this method to my question.

Comment: Why does it need to be static?

Comment: The call of this method (shown in the Update of the question) doesn't work for me, if I make this function non-static and create an instance of the `VatValidator`.
The parameter of `checkVat` is the FormControl the Validator is applied to, if I use an instance (`vatValidator`) and call the method like this: `vatValidator.checkVat(this.vatCtrl)` The compiler doesn't like that because of the parameter. This is a AsyncValidator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your validator class a bit, you don't need a static method

```
@Injectable()
class PatternValidator {
  constructor(private http:Http){}

  // this is a method that returns a validator function  
  // configured with a pattern
  pattern(pattern) {
    return (control:Control) => {
      this.http.get(...)

    ...
    }
  }
}
```

You can use it like:

- inject it to your component so DI passes it's dependencies in (`Http`)

```
constructor(private pattern:PatternValidator) {}
```

- pass it with `bind(pattern)` so `.this` keeps working inside the validator function

```
this.vatCtrl = new FormControl("", 
    Validators.compose([
        this.pattern(this.vatService.vatPattern).bind(this.pattern)
    ]), VatValidator.checkVat);
```

See also 
[Inject Http manually in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243525/inject-http-manually-in-angular-2)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, although I need this for the Custom AsyncValidator `VatValidator.checkVat` and not the pattern-Validator, which is angular2 native and I'm not really sure yet how to use it with it in this code:
`this.vatCtrl = new FormControl("", 
    Validators.compose([
        this.pattern(this.vatService.vatPattern).bind(pattern)
    ]), VatValidator.checkVat);`

Comment: Sorry for mixing these up. Should work the same for `checkVat`. `this.vatCtrl = new FormControl("", Validators.compose([ this.pattern(this.vatService.vatPattern)]), this.vatValidator.checkVat.bind(this.vatValidator))`

Comment: If you post more code (not in the comment - edit the question) I can provide more concrete feedback.

Comment: Great, glad to hear :)

Answer (score 12):

```
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, XHRBackend, ConnectionBackend, BrowserXhr, ResponseOptions, XSRFStrategy, BaseResponseOptions, CookieXSRFStrategy, RequestOptions, BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

class MyCookieXSRFStrategy extends CookieXSRFStrategy {}

...

let http =  ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        Http, BrowserXhr, 
        { provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: XHRBackend },
        { provide: ResponseOptions, useClass: BaseResponseOptions },
        { provide: XSRFStrategy, useClass: MyCookieXSRFStrategy },
        { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions }
      ]).get(Http);
```

Sure, you still need HttpModule included, enjoy!

Comment: This worked great but very clunky. @AlexV have you brought this up to Anuglar team as feature request to improve on this and make it easier?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I needed this. Agree with @ScottN, wish there was a better way to just grab the Http service that's out there.

Comment: Getting error: `Cannot resolve all parameters for 'MyCookieXSRFStrategy'` in Angular 4.0.0-rc3. Found solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243525/inject-http-manually-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

With and after RC5  what you can do is,

```
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,HttpModule ],  //<------HttpModule
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  providers:    [service],

  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

And In service or component,

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class service{
  constructor(private http:Http){}           //<----inject here

  // use http here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does not work because my method is static, I updatet my question.