# Using generated Swagger TypeScript Rest Client in Angular2

Tags: javascript, meteor, angular, typescript, swagger

I am working on a Meteor web application using Angular 2 and TypeScript. For using a REST API, I have generated client code with Swagger Codegen. Unfortunately there is no sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/typescript-angular2/npm), how to use the rest client.

I have an angular 2 view component which is injecting an Angular 2 service (ProductTreeService) and the generated API (both marked as "@Injectable"):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'panel-product-selection',
    template,
    providers: [ProductTreeService, UserApi],
    directives: [ProductTreeComponent]
})

export class PanelProductSelectionComponent
{
    private categoriesProductsTree: Collections.LinkedList<CategoryTreeElement>;
    private productTreeService: ProductTreeService;
    private userApi: UserApi;

    constructor(productTreeService: ProductTreeService, userApi: UserApi)
    {
        this.productTreeService = productTreeService;
        this.userApi = userApi;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

While the angular service only is accessable and all is working fine, the application is crashing when I inject UserApi. The only difference between UserApi and ProductTreeService is the constructor: The service has no constructor parameters, the generated [Api class](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/typescript-angular2/npm/api/UserApi.ts) has:

```
constructor(protected http: Http, @Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string) {
    if (basePath) {
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }
}
```

So how can I inject the generated API?

Comment: Can you please include some of the generated code? UserApi, isn't that just the sample provided? The code you linked to isn't meant to be included in projects -- it is a sample of generated code.

Comment: Here is an example using Typescript-angular2 API client generated by Swagger Codegen: https://github.com/taxpon/ng2-swagger-example. Would this help?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the environment.ts file with a property for the url:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  basePath: 'https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/user/project/1.0.0'
};
```

And then in the app.module you provide the config to the service:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: environment.basePath },
  ],
```

This works with Swagger generated code.

Hope that helps! (updated to Angular6+)

https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-manage-different-environments-with-angular-cli-883c26e99d15

Answer (score 2):

After further researches I got the solution. The constructor of the rest client [UserApi](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/typescript-angular2/npm/api/UserApi.ts) is expecting an HTTP provider as following:

```
constructor(protected http: Http, @Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string) {
    if (basePath) {
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }
}
```

Coming from Java, I thought maybe this provider has to be initialized somehow in the constructor which is injecting this API. In actual fact, this initialization has to be done in the NgModule containing the injecting component, as described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721276/angular-2-no-provider-for-http).

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but ... that's how you should do it:

```
providers: [
{
  provide: API_BASE_URL, // or BASE_PATH
  useFactory: () => { 
      return environment.apiBaseUrl // or return just "your base url as text"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Could you add some more information as to why that is the way it should be done.

Comment: Oh, it was just about the missing Http Provider. My solution is how you inject the base url into your auto generated clients

Comment: @PaD Could you show an example of how to do this when `apiBaseUrl` comes from a config JSON file that is loaded on APP_INITIALIZER?