# NoProviderError.Error (native)

Tags: mongodb, angular2-nativescript, angular2-seed

I am developing `angular2seedadvanced` app. I am referring to

- https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced

and sucessfully built the web and desktop application. But while building the nativescript app, it failed due to some errors. I am using loopback sdk builder (nativecsript).

- https://github.com/mean-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder/wiki

while building app using npm run start.android
an error occured

> NoProviderError.Error (native)

I couldn't find where this error occuring. What should I do? Any one please help me. Any help will highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular 2 No provider for Http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721276/angular-2-no-provider-for-http)
i had also same problem
just import 
HttpModule in appmodule.ts 
may this works