# No provider for Http Angular + Node.js API

Tags: node.js, angular, http, provider

[image]

I looked everywhere and could not find what I was doing wrong. I am using angular 2 to send a GET request to my node servers api and get information which it displays with databinding in my component called trade. The error occurs on the webbrowser when i try to view my angular app. Both my nodejs app and angular2 app are running on the same server.

Service:
https://hastebin.com/ileqekites.js

Component:
https://hastebin.com/agopopadus.cs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 No provider for Http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721276/angular-2-no-provider-for-http)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have HttpModule imported into one of your Angular modules?

Here is one of mine as an example:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';               // <- HERE
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';

/* Feature Modules */
import { ProductModule } from './products/product.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,                                          // <- HERE
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]),
    ProductModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```