# Angular 5 StaticInjectorError:[Http]

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, angular-http, angular5

hello i am getting such an error what is the reason for this?

StaticInjectorError[Http]: StaticInjectorError[Http]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Http! at NullInjector.get (core.js:923) at resolveToken (core.js:1211) at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)enter code here at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024) at resolveToken (core.js:1211) at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153) at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024) at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10585) at NgModuleRef.get (core.js:11806) at resolveDep (core.js:12302)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core' import {Todo} from './Todo'

import {Http, Response,Headers,RequestOptions} from '@angular/Http' import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable' import 'rxjs/add/operator/do' import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch' import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable() export class TodoService{

constructor(private http: Http){}

todoUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";

getTodos():Observable{ return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos") .map((res:Response)=>res.json()) .do(data=>console.log("TODOS LIST")) } }
```

Comment: Please format your code and your issue is probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721276/angular-2-no-provider-for-http Google is your friend ;)

Comment: import `HttpModule` and add to imports array of the respective module

Comment: Please add HttpModule into the imports:[] section of NgModule. It should work

Answer (score 5):

Try to import HttpClientModule  in your app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: Can we mark this as the best answer as it explains the exact cause of the issue? more information available here - https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1213737/Upgrade-to-Angular-and-HttpClient?msg=5461146

Comment: dont forget to mention that `private http: Http` should be `private http: HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

Import the `HttpClientModule` in the app.module.ts as mentioned in the example.
Thanks World! :)

```
 import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/http';

        @NgModule({
            imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpClientModule ],
            providers: [],
            declarations: [ AppComponent ],
            bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
        })
        export default class AppModule { }

        platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKCzv.png)

You didn't import `HttpModule` in (maybe you app.module.ts) in `NgModule` > `imports`