# Angular 2 accessing REST API error -No provider for Http

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developing a Angular 2 application to access REST API endpoints and show the data to users. I tested REST API endpoints in Postman and those are working well. When i'm accessing a GET endpoint from Angular i'm getting following error snippet.

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
at _NullInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1189)
at resolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1477)
at tryResolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1419)
at StaticInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1290)
at resolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1477)
at tryResolveToken (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1419)
at StaticInjector.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1290)
at resolveNgModuleDep (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11074)
at NgModuleRef_.get (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12306)
at resolveDep (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12804)
```

Tried by importing both Http and HttpModule like this top of the code as well.

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
```

Following is my relevant code snippet for the get data function.

```js
getData(){
    const url = 'http://localhost/laravel_app/public/api/getdata';
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      res => {
        const data = res.json();
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: You need to inject the HTTP Service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can import this line app.module.ts

```
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

and write in

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
    HttpModule,
   ]
 })
```

Comment: Did like this. Then i'm getting this error - Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Http' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: Finally it works. I have imported both Http and HttpModule. No need to import both as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code into your app.module.ts file.

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpModule       
]
```

Actually **http** is used in angular 2 but now in latest version of angular it used **HttpClient**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular v5 version, import HttpClientModule in your app.module.ts after HttpModule.

```
imports: [
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule
]
```

Comment: Using Angular 2 version not v5

Comment: what is the version

Comment: Angular version is 2

Comment: post your app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

you should import `HttpModule` in the module.ts file and the `Http` in the service where you are actually using it to make the api call.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721276/angular-exception-no-provider-for-http?rq=1)

Comment: There's no module.ts file.

Comment: I meant wherever you are defining you angular 2  module. may be app.module.ts